# In WebRTC only one camera works after connecting

Tags: reactjs, websocket, webrtc

I'm trying to write a program where the connection between two users is automatic. For this, WebSocket is used to send the description and the candidate. The problem is that after all the information has been sent, only one camera works. The other does not work because the camera is inactive in the media stream. I don't understand why that is

Here is the Code:
App.jsx

```
import { useEffect, } from 'react'
import { getMedia, connectionData} from './connection'
import './App.css'

function App() {


  useEffect(() => {

    connectionData.localStream = document.getElementById("localVideoStream");
    connectionData.remoteStream = document.getElementById("remoteStream");
    getMedia();


  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <video id ="localVideoStream" autoPlay></video>
      <video  id = "remoteStream" autoPlay style={{
        height: `${250}px`,
        width: `${250}px`,
        border: `solid ${1}px black`
      }}></video>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

connection.js

```
const webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/");

let connectionData = {
    pcConnection: new RTCPeerConnection(null),
    remoteStream: null,
    localStream: null,
    connectionCount: 0,
}

let candidateManager ={
    sendet:false,
    candidateAdded:false
};

let candidateSendet = false;
//für später
let connectionDataList = [];


//web Socket funktionen
webSocket.onopen = function (e) {

    createOffer();

}

webSocket.onmessage = function (e) {

    let sdpObject = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if (sdpObject.type == "offer") {
        console.log("offer");
        setRemoteDescription(sdpObject);
        createAnswer();
    }
    if (sdpObject.type == "answer") {
        console.log("answer");
        setRemoteDescription(sdpObject);
    }

    if (sdpObject.type == "candidate") {
        console.log("candidate");
        console.log(e);
        //console.log("streams: ", connectionData.remoteStream.srcObject);
        setCandidate(sdpObject.candidate);

    }

}

//stream functions
async function getMedia() {
    const constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: true,
    }

    await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(stream => {
            connectionData.localStream.srcObject = stream;
            stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
                //console.log("user Media", stream);
                connectionData.pcConnection.addTrack(track, stream);
            })
        })

}

function createOffer() {

    connectionData.pcConnection.createOffer({
        offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
        offerToReceiveVideo: 1,
    }).then(async sdp => {

        webSocket.send(JSON.stringify(sdp));
        await connectionData.pcConnection.setLocalDescription(sdp);

        candidateManager.sendet=false;
    });

}


function createAnswer() {

    connectionData.pcConnection.createAnswer({
        offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
        offerToReceiveVideo: 1,
    }).then(async sdp => {

        webSocket.send(JSON.stringify(sdp));
        await connectionData.pcConnection.setLocalDescription(sdp);
    });

}
async function setRemoteDescription(sdp) {
    await connectionData.pcConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp))
}

function setCandidate(candidate) {

    if (connectionData.pcConnection.remoteDescription != null) {
        connectionData.pcConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate)).catch((e)=>{
            console.log(`failure MESSAGE:${e.name}`)
          });;
          console.log(connectionData.remoteStream.srcObject);
    }
}

connectionData.pcConnection.onicecandidate = function (e) {

    if (e.candidate != null) {
        const candidate = {
            type: "candidate",
            candidate: e.candidate
        }
        if (candidate.candidate.protocol == "udp" && candidateManager.sendet==false) {
            webSocket.send(JSON.stringify(candidate));
            console.log("sendet Candidate",candidate);
            candidateManager.sendet = true;
        }
    }

}

connectionData.pcConnection.ontrack = (e) => {
    console.log("onTrack", e.streams[0]);
    connectionData.remoteStream.srcObject = e.streams[0];
    //console.log("remoteStream: ", e.streams);
}




export {
    webSocket,
    connectionData,
    getMedia,
    connectionDataList,
    candidateSendet
}
```

I compared the candidates who were sent, and I also had the descriptions issued to see whether they were correct and whether communication was working.

The communication works and is carried out correctly as far as possible. But I can't explain why the remote stream is inactive for a user

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution. The error is in the `setRemoteDescription` function. This function is asynchronous. But I executed this function on an `offer` and immediately called the `createAnswer` function. This means that an answer was created before the remoteDescription was actually set.

My solution is to make two functions out of the `setRemoteDescription` function and add a `than`. The functions look like this.

```
async function setRemoteDescriptionFromOffer(sdp) {
    await connectionData.pcConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp)).then((e)=>{
        createAnswer();
    }).catch((e)=>{
        console.log(`failure MESSAGE:${e.name}`)

    })
}

async function setRemoteDescriptionFromAnswer(sdp){
    await connectionData.pcConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp)).catch((e)=>{
        console.log(`failure MESSAGE:${e.name}`)
    })
}
```